# Best way to account for caching when measuring Oracle query performance?

Tags: oracle, caching, query-optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm in the process of measuring performance of an Oracle query executed on Exadata, but I do not want caching to affect (or rather improve) the performance.

One way I plan on doing so is by flushing the cache between each execution like so:

```
alter system flush buffer_cache;
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

However, this would require additional privileges for my user. So I came across this page regarding [Tuning the Result Cache](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA642) and it says:

> To exclude query results from the cache, the /*+ NO_RESULT_CACHE */
> query hint must be used.

So I used the hint, but the query took the same time to execute as without the hint. Am I maybe using it wrong?

Also, the aforementioned page says that if caching occurs, this will be mentioned in the execution plan like so:

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id | Operation          | Name                       |Rows
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> | 0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                            | 11
> | 1 |  RESULT CACHE       | 8fpza04gtwsfr6n595au15yj4y |
> | 2 |   HASH GROUP BY     |                            | 11
> | 3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEES                  | 107
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

However, I do not see a RESULT CACHE line in my execution plan. Does that suggest that Oracle is not caching the results of my query?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different caches so you'd need to be very specific about which caches you want to avoid.

Within the database, you have the buffer cache which caches recently accessed database blocks and the query results cache which materializes the result of queries.  The overwhelming majority of queries use the buffer cache, the overwhelming majority of queries do not use the query results cache.  You have to specifically identify which queries you want to use the query results cache.  Your plan shows that your query isn't using the query results cache.  But it would still be using the data in the buffer cache.  Depending on your architecture, you could have additional caches that are of note-- in-memory tables are a type of cache, TimesTen is a cache that lives in front of the Oracle database, the SQL cache determines whether a query has already been parsed or whether it needs to be parsed again which, for some queries, can be a meaningful fraction of its execution time, etc.

On an Exadata box, you also have a bunch of caches at the storage level that will impact query runtime.  You've got a Cell RAM Cache and a Flash Cache, for example.  And the database itself isn't going to know (or control) whether the storage subsystem has decided to put a particular piece of a file on flash disk or on spinning disk.

You could flush the buffer cache and ignore the impacts of caching at the storage system level.  Since the buffer cache is a shared resource, however, that is not something that you can generally do in a multi-user environment or in a production environment.  It also sets up a rather non-representative test environment-- your query will basically never actually be run with a completely empty database buffer cache and the query that runs the fastest with an empty database buffer cache may not be the most efficient query when the buffer cache is reasonably warm.

If you're trying to tune a query, I would focus much more on metrics that don't change based on cache-- logical reads and CPU time.  Most likely, if you reduce the amount of logical I/O a query does, you'll get results faster regardless of how many blocks are found in various caches.